# Testing history.goback with testing-library and react

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, testing-library

I'm trying to check the goback navigation in this component:

```js
class BackMore extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="backMore">
        <div className="back" onClick={ this.props.history.goBack } data-testid="go-back">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faArrowLeft} />
        </div>
        <span className="title">{ this.props.title }</span>
        <More/>
      </div>)
  }
}

export default withRouter(BackMore)
```

I use `testing-library` and the recipe from page https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-router

```
// test utils file
function renderWithRouter(
  ui,
  {
    route = '/',
    history = createMemoryHistory({ initialEntries: [route] }),
  } = {}
) {
  const Wrapper = ({ children }) => (
    <Router history={history}>{children}</Router>
  )
  return {
    ...render(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper }),
    // adding `history` to the returned utilities to allow us
    // to reference it in our tests (just try to avoid using
    // this to test implementation details).
    history,
  }
}
```

And this is my test:

```
test('Go back in the history', () =>{
  const browserHistory = createMemoryHistory()
  browserHistory.push('/my-learning');
  const { history } = RenderWithRouter(<BackMore />, { route: ['my-learning'], history: browserHistory });
  userEvent.click(screen.getByTestId(/go-back/i));
  expect(history.location.pathname).toBe('/')
})
```

The `history.location.pathname` variable is 'my-learning' and it should be '/'

What is it wrong?

Comment: You've provided default value for route as '/', but while calling you're providing 'my-learning' as current route, so I think it will be the current pathName which is correct.

Comment: I've 2 entries in the histoy:



history.entries
Array(2) [Object, Object]
length:2
__proto__:Array(0) [, …]
0:Object {pathname: "/", search: "", hash: "", …}
1:Object {pathname: "/my-learning", search: "", hash: "", …}



And the first it is '/'

Comment: I have the same issue here. Manually it works in the browser but when try to assert on history object after clicking a button that calls history.goBack() the history.location object does not update